# d3: reading timestamps from csv file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My csv file looks like this:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11
2015-08-20 00-01-05,1,01,00,05,109
2015-08-20 00-01-10,2,10,00,06,109
2015-08-20 00-01-14,3,04,00,05,109
```

and I am trying to read the file like this:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S ").parse;
...
d3.csv(file,function(a){
       d=a.map(function(d1) {
       return[
            parseDate(+d1["c1"]),
           +d1["c2"]
       ];
    });
```

My problem is that on the console, I am getting gibberish. For example, the timestamp is always NaN. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify the time format correctly -- `"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"`. And don't convert the field to a number before parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I did correct the format to "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S". Still no luck.

Comment: Are you parsing the date as a string now?

Comment: Ideally I would like to read column c1 only as seconds since midnight (and ignore the date); but yes I am reading it as string. (or atleast that I what I think I am doing)

Comment: You should be doing `parseDate(d1["c1"])`.